# Can you look for a job in the UK without a visa?

Tags: uk, work

A lot of news reports appearing lately of visitors to the UK from elsewhere in Europe being detained and deported for entering with the intention to work illegally. e.g.

https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-citizens-detained-uk-work-visas-brexit/

Some of these stories seem really quite shocking and potentially very dodgy.

It is known that coming to the UK and **working** without a visa is illegal and should get you this treatment. However; what of coming to the UK as a visitor with the intention to try to get a job, albeit **not to work** it, on that visit?

Just what is the legal situation around coming to the UK for job hunting without a work visa?

I think it's pretty certain that coming for a pre-arranged interview is completely fine. But what about applying for a job whilst you are in the country?- again, assuming there is no intention to actually work illegally and to get your documents in order before you start doing any work.

Comment: This surely happens often, and the company will/should help you getting a work visa with the hiring confirmation. ?

Comment: In these days when everything is done on the internet, the first question is going to be "why do you need to come to the UK to look for a job, when you could do it just as well from outside the country?". What will your answer be?

Comment: Even if you were successful in finding a job, you would have to exit and apply for your work visa from outside the UK. There is no mechanism to switch from visitor status to work visa from within the UK

Comment: Yes, people are routinely turned away from the UK for showing up with a bunch of office clothes and CVs in their luggage.  UK doesn't want people coming in and taking jobs that should go to Brits, *that was kinda the point* of Brexit.  However, there's an exception for job classes where they just can't find Brits.  This is more for "submillimeter waveguide engineer" than "dishwasher at Chinese takeaway".

Comment: The answer is simply: don't do this. There are better targets than the UK.

Comment: Though applying online from anywhere in the world is technically fine, it goes without saying that employers will always favour locally available candidates who could potentially interview at reasonably short notice. I don't think it's so daft that people would want to apply from within the UK if working in the UK is something they specifically want to do.

Comment: @theotherone if you don’t have a work visa you are not a “locally available candidate”. You are a candidate who will need to go back to your country, apply for a work visa, get it, receive the visa, move, blah blah blah. Don’t try to pretend you’re a local candidate. This is fooling the employer and yourself. If that’s your plan, chances you will be turned down at the border are quite high.

Comment: @jcaron I don't think you understand quite how easy travel between countries in Europe is. Somebody from Madrid is far more locally available to an employer in London than somebody from say Blackpool. There's no "Fooling" at all here, if somebody is in a city then they're in that city and available to interview at short notice, if they're not then they're not. This has nothing to do with visa status.

Comment: @theotherone your comment is self-contradictory. You're saying it's easier to travel from Madrid to London than from Blackpool to London, which goes in favour of applying online and then going to London for the interview if you are selected for one, you can literally be there the next day. But that doesn't make you a locally available candidate.

Comment: Yes it does. Its the definition of the term.

Comment: FYI another story from today: [EU citizens arriving in UK being locked up and expelled](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2021/may/13/eu-citizens-arriving-in-uk-being-locked-up-and-expelled) _Europeans with job interviews tell of detentions and expulsions despite rules allowing non-visa holders to attend interviews_

Comment: And 24 hours later: [2021-05-14 15:22: Hostile UK border regime traumatises visitors from EU | Brexit | The Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/politics/2021/may/14/hostile-uk-border-regime-traumatises-visitors-from-eu) *Giuseppe had provided her with a letter “outlining she could come and stay with us as an au pair, not realising that work, paid or not, is not permissible post-Brexit without a visa”.*

Comment: @theotherone no, if you are not allowed to work, you are not locally available, even if you can hop on a plane.

Answer (score 5):

**It is absolutely legal to look for work on a UK business visa** (meaning a standard visitor visa). You do not need a work permit. However there are some serious traps that you can fall into.

- If you have a pre-arranged interview, you will be fine (as long as the job is real and one for which you could reasonably expect to be given a work permit.) If you need to come to the UK for an interview, apply for a standard visitor visa.
- It must be realistic and necessary that you have to come to the UK to look for work. Frankly that is extremely unlikely to be true for the pre-interview stage. Every job above retail server allows - no, requires - that you apply online. You will never get a work visa for a low level job, so there is no point in applying for them. For every other job you gain no benefit from being in the country, so why would you spend money to come to the UK? Immigration will assume that you have another agenda, and you will probably be denied a visa.
- If you say you are coming as a tourist, but they find evidence that you are coming as a job hunter you will be banned for deception. It doesn't matter that looking for work is legal on the visa you have - you lied about your purpose. Now if you are genuinely on holiday and genuinely coincidentally run into someone who offers you a job, that will probably be OK, but any pre-planning will get you in trouble.

Comment: There’s no such thing as a UK business visitor visa. Certain business-related activities are allowed within the rules of the Standard Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities Looking for work as the main purpose of a visit is not listed as a permitted activity. Attending a meeting/interview is however allowed, proof from the inviting organisation would be expected IMHO

Comment: I'm aware of that. But it's a commonly used term, and I'm using it to indicate that the user needs to specify business as the reason for travel.

Comment: "If you need to come to the UK for an interview, apply for a standard visitor visa": the question is about non-visa nationals.  It's not necessary for such people to apply for a visa. "It must be realistic and necessary that you have to come to the UK to look for work": where does this requirement arise? Suppose I have a dream of working in London; why can't I just go to London and knock on doors of businesses to ask why they're hiring?  "Any pre-planning will get you in trouble": only if you have claimed to be a tourist. If you say you're coming for professional reasons then planning is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything legally preventing you from doing so.

However, see it from the perspective of an immigration officer. How can they be sure that once you've found a job you won't start working right away?

Then you have the fact that if the job can wait a little while for you to start (usually more qualified jobs, where prospective employers are willing to wait for you to end your notice period with your previous employer, deal with visa issues, and usually with slightly longer processes, multiple phone and face-to-face interviews...), then there's no reason for you to arrive in the UK first and look for jobs while there: you can do all the initial preparation (apply, go through phone interviews...) while outside of the UK, then plan face-to-face interviews and get to the UK for those.

On the other hand, jobs where you could find an opening quickly via a more direct door-to-door type approach are usually lower paid jobs, where you are expected to start quickly, definitely not with enough time to get back home, apply for a work visa, get one, move, etc.

In regular times, the chances of you slipping through the net would be quite large. Only if something tips them off and they start digging would there be an issue. But in this period where travel is often restricted, IOs will naturally be a little more inquisitive of the reasons you are coming to the UK, and once you say "I'm looking for work", they won't hear the "but I won't be working on this visit, just looking for a job".

If you've watched any of the "Border protection" shows, you must have seen that finding a pile of resumes in your bag, or a suit and tie when you pretend you're on holiday, usually ends up badly.

Don't forget the UK are flexing their muscles to try show that they are left with a shred of power after Brexit. You don't want to get caught up in that. Not only is it highly inconvenient and uncomfortable on the spot, but it will in addition leave a stain on your record, so be extremely careful.

Comment: The UK is not ‘flexing their muscles’ after Brexit any more than the EU is flexing its muscles by applying the 90/180 rule. The rules changed as a result of Brexit, simple as that.

Comment: No it's definitely valid to say the UK this past few years has been particularly draconian on immigration.

Comment: @Traveller how many British citizens have been detained in immigration detention in the EU recently?

Comment: @phoog At least 500? https://www.majorcadailybulletin.com/news/local/2021/03/29/81645/british-expats-face-deportation.html And others with legal resident status were denied entry https://www.thelocal.dk/20210104/brexit-we-warned-you-call-for-action-after-britons-living-in-eu-denied-entry/  How many people are detained in eg US immigration for being suspected of intending to work? I’m not denying the reports about the UK. I object to the ‘flexing their muscles’ opinion-based element of the answer, is all.

Comment: @Traveler I don't see any mention of detention in those articles.